# Unknown cpu type when compiling OpenSSL FIPS Capable libraries for arm64 or arm7s

Tags: ios, openssl, fips

I can successfully (at least without warnings and with resulting .a files) compile for arm7, x86_64, and i386.

When I compile for arm64, I get `Unknown cpu type 100000c, no adjustments made`. When I compile for arm7s, I get `Unknown cpu type 100000c, no adjustments made`. The script for those two architectures, which is modified from and uses environment scripts from https://github.com/noloader/openssl-1.0.1i-ios is below including arm7, which works and arm7s and arm64, followed by a log tail for arm64. The scripts build non-fips libraries successfully before modification. incore_macho and fips canisters are pre-generated and referenced from this script. I created the fips canisters similarly by modifying instructions from the OpenSSL FIPS 2.0 User Guide iOS appendix, which is incredibly dated and does not work on its own. How can one compile a FIPS capable library for these two platforms?

*Edit:*

I see that libssl.a and libcrypto.a have actually been created and have the correct architectures, but incore_macho returns an identical `Unknown cpu type` error.

*Update:*

Using a copy of incore_macho that is updated for armv7 from @jww at https://github.com/noloader/incore_macho, it now compiles without error for arm7s, so I'm now under the assumption that core_macho may need to be updated for arm64. Can this be done?

```
sed -i "" 's|\"iphoneos-cross\"\,\"llvm-gcc\:-O3|\"iphoneos-cross\"\,\"clang\:-Os|g' Configure
sed -i "" 's/CC= cc/CC= clang/g' Makefile.org
sed -i "" 's/CFLAG= -O/CFLAG= -Os/g' Makefile.org
sed -i "" 's/MAKEDEPPROG=makedepend/MAKEDEPPROG=$(CC) -M/g' Makefile.org

export LANG=$OLD_LANG
export CC=clang
export IOS_INSTALLDIR="/usr/local/ssl/ios"
unset OPENSSLDIR

################################################################
# Third, build ARMv7
echo "****************************************"
THIS_ARCH=armv7
unset CROSS_ARCH

. ./setenv-ios-$THIS_ARCH.sh
export HOSTCC=/usr/bin/cc
export HOSTCFLAGS="-arch i386"
export FIPS_SIG="/tmp/incore_macho"

./config fips -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-asm -no-shared -no-hw -no-engine --with-fipsdir="/tmp/openssl fips-2.0.1-iOS-${THIS_ARCH}" --openssldir=$IOS_INSTALLDIR
sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 !" "Makefile"
make clean 2>&1>/dev/null && make all
mkdir $THIS_ARCH
\cp ./libcrypto.a $THIS_ARCH/libcrypto.a
\cp ./libssl.a $THIS_ARCH/libssl.a

################################################################
# Fourth, build ARMv7s
echo "****************************************"
THIS_ARCH=armv7s
unset CROSS_ARCH

. ./setenv-ios-$THIS_ARCH.sh
export HOSTCC=/usr/bin/cc
export HOSTCFLAGS="-arch i386"
export FIPS_SIG="/tmp/incore_macho"

./config fips -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-asm -no-shared -no-hw -no-engine --with-fipsdir="/tmp/openssl-fips-2.0.1-iOS-${THIS_ARCH}" --openssldir=$IOS_INSTALLDIR
sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 !" "Makefile"
make clean 2>&1>/dev/null && make all
mkdir $THIS_ARCH
\cp ./libcrypto.a $THIS_ARCH/libcrypto.a
\cp ./libssl.a $THIS_ARCH/libssl.a

################################################################
# Fifth, build ARM64
#echo "****************************************"
THIS_ARCH=arm64
unset CROSS_ARCH

. ./setenv-ios-$THIS_ARCH.sh
export HOSTCC=/usr/bin/cc
export HOSTCFLAGS="-arch i386"
export FIPS_SIG="/tmp/incore_macho"

./config fips -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-asm -no-shared -no-hw -no-engine --with-fipsdir="/tmp/openssl-fips-2.0.1-iOS-${THIS_ARCH}" --openssldir=$IOS_INSTALLDIR
sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 !" "Makefile"
make clean 2>&1>/dev/null && make all
mkdir $THIS_ARCH
\cp ./libcrypto.a $THIS_ARCH/libcrypto.a
\cp ./libssl.a $THIS_ARCH/libssl.a
```

tail of output for arm64:

```
shlib_target=; if [ -n "" ]; then \
        shlib_target="darwin-shared"; \
    elif [ -n "libcrypto" ]; then \
      FIPSLD_CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"; CC=/tmp/openssl-fips-2.0.1-iOS-arm64/bin/fipsld; export CC FIPSLD_CC; \
    fi; \
    LIBRARIES="-L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto" ; \
    make -f ../Makefile.shared -e \
        APPNAME=openssl OBJECTS="openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o" \
        LIBDEPS="-Wl,-search_paths_first $LIBRARIES " \
        link_app.${shlib_target}
( :; LIBDEPS="${LIBDEPS:--Wl,-search_paths_first -L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto }"; LDCMD="${LDCMD:-/tmp/openssl-fips-2.0.1-iOS-arm64/bin/fipsld}"; LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=7.1  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch arm64 -Os -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-common -I/tmp/openssl-fips-2.0.1-iOS-arm64/include}"; LIBPATH=`for x in $LIBDEPS; do echo $x; done | sed -e 's/^ *-L//;t' -e d | uniq`; LIBPATH=`echo $LIBPATH | sed -e 's/ /:/g'`; LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${APPNAME:=openssl} openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o ${LIBDEPS} )
Unknown cpu type 100000c, no adjustments made
```

Comment: *"Unknown cpu type"* - I think the problem is actually with the CPU subtype, and not the CPU type. There's a new `incore_macho` on that GitHub that recognizes the subtype and provides a more meaningful error message. I don't have an ARM64 device to test on, so I don't know for certain if the changes are any good. noloader, gmail account would probably be best to coordinate.

Comment: Thanks. As of early October it wasn't working without heavy modification. I'd love to hear if anyone gets it working in newer versions.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese i know this question is old but do you still have your scripts to compile a FIPS compatible openssl version for iOS for armv7 and arm64?

Comment: Yes, and I'm not sure if this represents my final effort. I modified others' public work to build a library with multiple architectures. https://gist.github.com/peterdeweese/db7cbacb66b21c8c67fd1a86b3a6d7c4

Comment: @PeterDeWeese I saw a similar script like that but was having issues getting the FIPS module to compile for multiple architectures. It seems the gist you have is a referencing the fips source but in reality it is building the openssl library.

Comment: Yes, because the fips compatible way was unable to build to every architecture. If you change anything, such as this, it won't fips verify, so it isn't technically fips.

Comment: So instead I get clients to choose. Since OpenSSL FIPS is a wreck, use Apple's newer built in CoreCrypto, which is FIPS validated, faster, and more secure, or use the latest OpenSSL without FIPS validation, which is more secure also. "Architects" often confuse standards and ancient decisions with requirements, so I force the difference into perspective. If you want to work through your build issues, DM me through my profile links, maybe with a link to a new SO question.

Comment: Hii @PeterDeWeese ,did you find any solution for this ARM64 support?

Comment: Not sure. Hopefully, there are new releases that support it. If they haven't made a release that cleanly supports it, making changes will allow it to compile but not allow the validation script to succeed, leaving you with FIPS compliance only in spirit. iOS itself is FIPS compliant, so the best option is to find a way to avoid OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3):

It will work if you add this to cpu_adjustment[]

```
CPU_TYPE_ARM64,   CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_ALL,  12, 12 ,
```

For reference:

```
#define CPU_ARCH_ABI64  0x01000000      /* 64 bit ABI */

#define CPU_TYPE_ARM64          (CPU_TYPE_ARM | CPU_ARCH_ABI64)

/*
 *  ARM64 subtypes
 */
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_ALL           ((cpu_subtype_t) 0)
```

Finding the adjustment was fun. ;-)

Comment: @PeterDeWeese - I don't believe it will invalidate the validation. The source code for the *FIPS Object Module* is sequestered and you are allowed to modify it. The procedure to build the *FIPS Object Module* is also rigid and cannot be modified. However, you are allowed to modify supporting files within reason, like `fipsld` and `incore_macho`. *"Within reason"* is subjective and open to interpretation, but it effectively means you don't adversely effect the *FIPS Object Module*. There's an OpenSSL User mailing list question about it, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Cool. I could not however get it to pass validation after adding or changing architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the CPU type before, so it's doable.   You may also need to modify the CPU adjustment as well.   You need to add an entry to cpu_adjustment[] in incore_macho.c and cputype

I think for arm64 it is CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_V8 I do not know the adjustment.   Please let us know if you get this to work